# Need my storm door to open widely for a move

Tags: glass, storm-door

We live in a small apt complex that for some reason has glass storm doors. Our front door and storm door open on the right hand side just inches away from a wall. If that weren't enough, once the storm door is open there's roughly 10 inches or so between the railing and storm door. When moving in we took the storm door completely off but don't want to do that again. I want it to open as close to 180 degrees just for our move out. How can we do that? [image] [image]

Comment: A picture would be a good thing to add to this question...  It's hard to understand how the door is up against a wall and 10" away from a railing but somehow you expect to open it 180 degrees... and without taking the door off like you did when you moved in...

Comment: I would recommend removing it.  Glass and moving stuff can lead to oops moments and for the short time of removing hinges, I would like to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing would be to remove the door, but if you don't want to do that, you should be able to disconnect the pin from the closer cylinder (see image below) and stop chain (if equipped) to get it to open up all the way.

[image: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Screen+Door+Closer+Replacement/100136]

That would be faster than removing the door and the glass would be somewhat more protected than leaving the door at a right angle.

Comment: Thanks so much, I could only guess about that pin but wanted to make sure. Getting the storm door off to move in took longer than expected and I want to avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: Yeah... taking it off entirely (and reinstalling it) is one of those jobs that sounds easy but ends up taking a lot more time and cussing than anticipated.

Answer (score 3):

> When moving in we took the storm door completely off but don't want to do that again.

So? Moving's not really any different in than out, door-removal-wise. Take it off, even if you'd rather not, or you'll probably regret the time you "saved" and waste more time (or break it and blow your damage deposit.)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. We had a bad experience with removing it at move in and it took far longer than we (apparently wrongly) expected so we will take the chance and remove the pin when moving out. I absolutely hate the thing, there is no need for it here and it's only been a hassle.